# assigning server responses (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular

I send the content of the "Galleries" constant to the API using "exportGalleries ()" but I do not know how to change the display of the server response instead of the local content in the "gallery.component" component

I will be ready for any help

gallery.component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-gallery',
  templateUrl: './gallery.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gallery.component.scss']
})
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {

  private galleryId: string;
  private gallery: IGallery;



  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.galleryId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('galleryId');
    this.gallery = Galleries.find((item: IGallery) => item.galleryId === this.galleryId);
    console.log("GALL");
    console.log(this.gallery);
  }

}
```

```js
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.title='Galeria';
    this.description='Wakacje';

    this.galleries = [];

    this.http.get('http://project.usagi.pl/gallery',
    this.httpOptions).toPromise().then((response: IGallery[]) => {
        console.log(response);
      this.galleries = response;
      });
    this.searchValue ='';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  setSearchValue($event) {
    console.log($event);
    this.searchValue=$event;
  }

  exportGalleries() {
    Galleries.forEach((gallery: IGallery) => {
      delete(gallery.galleryId);
      this.http.post('http://project.usagi.pl/gallery', gallery,
        this.httpOptions).toPromise().then((response: IGallery) => {
        console.log('success', response);
        this.galleries.push(response);
      }, (errResponse) => {
        console.log('error', errResponse);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: There is not enough to go by here with too many assumptions that must be made. Must assume the second file listing is the `app.component.ts` file must assume `Galleries` is some type of collection that is not defined here, etc. Please put your code up on stackblitz so we can get a better idea of what you are attempting.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-je9f9m

Comment: That is an empty application that does not include your code. Can you repost a proper link to your app in stackblitz?

Comment: Try it again https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-je9f9m

Comment: App won't run, I'm sure you realize that. But besides that, I don't see `<app-gallery>` used in any template file anywhere in the application. Can you tell me where to find it please?

Comment: https://github.com/TomBaut/AngGal

Comment: I'm giving you my time and really, really trying to help. Your question specifically mentions the gallery.component component - yet you don't use that component any where in your application. I recommend you start there. But, since you don't care to respond to reasonable questions, I'm out. Good luck.